# PS - Color changeable object using SVG

Tags: adobe-photoshop, svg, transparency

I'm using Photoshop CC 2015.

For webshop needs I have to create svg file from the below image. The plan is that the color of the object from the image can be fully changed without loos of object relief. The object is the blanket which has the tiny hairs that should be visible regardless of color change. The color of the blanket on the image should be as close as possible to a RGB color that user has entered.

So, I was thinking of making two layers. Bottom layer fully colored by user choice. And the top layer white, i.e. 40% transparent. But, done so, the problem is that the color of the blanket is not as the entered color, as the top layer changes the full image color. So, that doesn't work for me.

Is there any tool in PS that could change the blanket color by entering only RGB color, but that the image remains realistic? Any other ideas how to achieve this?

As I said, it's important that I can change the color programmatically via SVG.

[image]

**Edit 1:**

Thanks to @Scott solution I have achieved what I wanted. But, the problem with exporting to SVG occurred.

As stated in @Scott solution, I made two layers: Bottom "Layer 0" (100% fill, normal bend mode) layer and top "Color Fill 1" (100% fill, Hue bend mode) layer shown on the next image...

[image]

When the export to SVG is done, this is what opens in browser

[image]

**Edit 2:**

I made the next example to show the problem.

[image]

This is the SVG export window

[image]

Comment: Is it important that the color can be changed programmatically or that the picture format is svg? Because it doesn't need to be an svg for you to change the color programmatically.

Comment: Agree with @Joonas - We are venturing into SO territory, but if you are running PHP for example you may have access to ImageMagick or the GD Lib, which both have options to address this.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work....

- Lighting layer (raster) of the pillow in greyscale with its blend mode set to `Multiply`
- A solid color fill layer
- Export as SVG and the CSS could be altered to change the color fill layer

---

[image]

```
 <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #00aeef;
        fill-rule: evenodd;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        mix-blend-mode: multiply;
      }
    </style>
```

---

[image]

```
 <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: red;
        fill-rule: evenodd;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        mix-blend-mode: multiply;
      }
    </style>
```

---

The `Multiply` mode is important so it only darkens the color adding shadows. Without the proper blend mode, the greyscale layer will alter the overall luminosity of the color fill layer, both light and dark, changing the percieved color.

---

As @mayersdesign points out in the comment below, the `Multiply` mode may not be supported widely enough. You can instead *reverse* the layer stack and use the `Hue` blending mode on the color fill layer - leaving the raster image set to `Normal` mode. `Hue` is slightly more supported.

[image]

[image]

Color change would still merely require CSS editing:

```
 <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #06fb00;
        fill-rule: evenodd;
        mix-blend-mode: hue;
      }
    </style>
```

I did apply a **Levels** correction to the raster image to lighten it a bit so it results in a more color-accurate image. I merely chose `Image > Adjustments > Levels` and clicked the `Auto` button.

[image]

---

<sub>I am unable to attached the actual SVG here due to site limitations. Imgur doesn't accept svg and trying to paste the code inline for the svg seems to lock up the site (in Chrome/Mac anyway).</sub>

Comment: Watch out for support for mix-blend-mode https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode but a cool, and CSS only solution

Comment: Excellent point @mayersdesign -- One could extract the white from the raster image leaving only the dark, black, pixels at a lower opacity and possibly forego the multiply mode.

Comment: Thanks guys, really appreciate the help, and indeed it was a great help, as the results are great. But, I have some problems with exporting such an image with two layers. I went to File -> Export -> Export As -> Svg, but the preview shows the strange. On the preview, one layer is bigger than the other and it is not the same as when exporting to png for example. The I succeeded with exporting, but I had to merge layers. After merging the layers and exporting like that, class "cls-1" doesn't contain the "fill" property, so I can't change the fill color. What am I doing wrong while exporting?

Comment: Well you *can't* merge the layers. Then its 1 object not 2 and there's no fill property for the raster element. The key to this is having a separate SVG object which you can alter the color for. I don't know why you'd have 2 *different size* layers.

Comment: Dear @Scott, please check the post edit. Thanks

Comment: @user6549162 no clue why you are using smart filters. As you see above in my images I merely have a *solid vector layer with a flat color fill used for the hue*. I think you are overcomplicating the image. If you need 2 pillows stacked, do that in the HTML with 2 SVG images.. not in the image.